# GitFlow feature finish does not merge the feature branch into develop

Tags: git, git-flow

i've incurred onto an issue on my local machine related to git-flow.

Following the working tree i should do the following operations:

- git flow feature start X
- commit 1 (no push)
- commit 2 (no push)
- git flow feature finish X

On finish the git flow should push my commits onto the new branch "X" and should merge the content into "Develop".

However it seems that i have an issue related to it, on finish it does close the local feature branch, it does not merge remotely.

Also, for further information i am the only one working on this repository, so i did discard the possibility of "develop" beeing ahead of my local feature branch.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git-flow` will not merge it to remote `develop` branch. It will merge to local `develop` branch. You need to push it manually. So this is expected behavior.

Comment: You may be right, thanks